# Crash wen tapping "Open in Instagram" while using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I have got the following class:

.h file :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CHTInstagramSharer : NSObject<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;
-(void) sharePic:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CHTInstagramSharer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BaseController.h"

@implementation CHTInstagramSharer


-(void) sharePic:(UIImage *)image{    

    NSString * jpgPath = [Utils saveImage:image toFile:@"cover.igo"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jpgPath];
    self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url];
    self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.dic.delegate = self;
    self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Caption Test" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)    inView:[BaseController sharedInstance].view animated: YES ];
}
@end
```

It presents the controller with the option "Open in Instagram", but when I tap on that, the app crashes.

Any idea why?

Complementary information, when I look at the url in the debugger, I get: 
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/53435781-3BAB-4B02-A80C-FC088F696AE8/Library/Caches/cover.igo

The crash seems to happen in [_UIOpenWithAppActivity performActivity] when I look in the stack trace.

Comment: What is the crash? Uncaught exception? bad access? out of bounds access?

Comment: See my updated response, you should be able to copy and paste the method I created and use it in your app. Hope it helps.

Comment: bad access. I found the problem, it was just a deallocation of the sharer object happening too early.

Comment: I can't seem to get the annotations to carry over into Instagram - the caption is just empty. Anyone have experience with that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are not retaining the document controller. I use the Instagram hook like this:

**EDIT: Modified for ARC**

```
- (void)sharePic:(UIImage *)image {

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];

    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageUrl];
    [docController retain];
    docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    docController.delegate = self;
    docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Caption Test" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    docController = nil;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read a little bit further, there is : Alternatively, if you want to show only Instagram in the application list (instead of Instagram plus any other public/jpeg-conforming apps) you can specify the extension class igo, which is of type com.instagram.exclusivegram.

Comment: I see, you are correct. That must have been added after I used the API hook. Read my edited respond, it looks like you are not retaining the DocumentController.

Comment: That's because I am using ARC.

Comment: Take a look at my updated response, I modified it to work with ARC. Also you still need to retain the Document Controller. That is why it is crashing for you. One with thing, you should not hard code the CGRect Values. Use my example because that way you do not have to worry about the device screen size changing on you. One other thing, do you need to have a property for the DocumentController? Why not instantiate the object when you need it?

Comment: You were right about the fact that the problem was a deallocation happening too early. The sharer was deallocated before the end of the process. I changed that and now it works. That said, in Arc, the code you proposed cannot work, since retain is not allowed.

Comment: You can still retain in ARC FYI. I tested the solution in an ARC project. You can still use manual memory management in ARC projects and remember ARC is not an end all solution, for example Core Foundation still requires manual memory management. Please accept my accept answer. Thank you. Good Luck!

Comment: I tried the retain too, but xcode just won't compile with it.

Comment: When using ARC, you can make the UIDocumentInteractionController a strong property and it works.

Comment: If you make it a retain property it works... @property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;

Comment: I can't seem to get the annotations to carry over into Instagram - the caption is just empty. Anyone have experience with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Me too face the same issue, Declaring the `UIDocumentInteractionController *docController` commonly on `@interface` worked for me!

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
 UIDocumentInteractionController * docController;
}
@end 

- (void)sharePic:(UIImage *)image {

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.ig"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savedImagePath];

docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageUrl];
[docController retain];
docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
docController.delegate = self;
docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Caption Test" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
[docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
docController = nil;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)