# crash app when click "Open in Instagram" - objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios7, instagram, ios7.1

My app crash when click on "Open in Instagram" .. iOS7

My code is: .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)     UIDocumentInteractionController* docController;
```

And in .m file:

```
 NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.ig"];
 NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

_docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];//[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]];
_docController.delegate=self;
_docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
[_docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view.frame inView:appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view animated:YES];
```

Also I used:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view.bounds.size, appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view.opaque, 0.0);
[appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.ig"];

NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

_docfile.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
_docfile = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
_docfile=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
[_docfile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view animated: YES ];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [_docfile presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect inView: appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view animated: YES ];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
}
```

Also:

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL usingDelegate: (id) interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
   interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

   return interactionController;
```

}

the stack trace:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x37c2b636 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x300f7442 in -[_UIOpenWithAppActivity performActivity] ()
#2  0x2feadad0 in -[UIActivityViewController _executeActivity] ()
#3  0x2fead4b8 in -[UIActivityViewController _performActivity:] ()
#4  0x300f7b0a in -[_UIDocumentActivityViewController _performActivity:] ()
#5  0x2fead068 in -[UIActivityGroupViewController collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] ()
#6  0x2feacc8e in -[UICollectionView _userSelectItemAtIndexPath:] ()
#7  0x2feac974 in -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#8  0x2fe17794 in forwardTouchMethod ()
#9  0x2fe17794 in forwardTouchMethod ()
#10 0x2fcc5720 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#11 0x2fcc06ea in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#12 0x2fc958ec in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#13 0x2fc93f96 in _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue ()
#14 0x2d44025a in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#15 0x2d43f72a in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#16 0x2d43df1e in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#17 0x2d3a8f4e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#18 0x2d3a8d32 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#19 0x322ad662 in GSEventRunModal ()
#20 0x2fcf416c in UIApplicationMain ()
#21 0x001009ce in main at /Epic MAR/samples/Epic MAR/ImageTargets/main.m:13
#22 0x00100958 in start ()
```

---

After make Exception Breakpoint, a msg appears in log:

```
-[__NSCFSet _openDocumentWithApplication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb95d00
```

What is the problem ?

Also, Do I need to integrate with Instagram ?, make app and set appID like Facebook ?

Thank you,

Comment: Put the stack trace into your question.

Comment: No error description found in trace, Only crash in main.m file with error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS, at this line: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"ImageTargetsAppDelegate");

Comment: That's not true; there will alway be a trace of some kind either within Xcode or within a log file.  Without it you have no hope of either you or us finding the issue.  Keep looking.

Comment: I'm new in iOS and Xcode sorry, I updated my question, Is that stack trace? can it be useful?

Comment: Yep that's the one.  Now there will also be an exception reason text knocking about too, which is very useful to know.

Comment: sorry, but how can I get it?, I didn't find this line in stack trace to follow: "objc_exception_throw"

Comment: OK so I assume that Xcode stopped at that line?  If so you need to *continue* so that the exception bubbles to the top where it will be printed to the console.

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you for reply, but i didn't understood what you mean, i read that this crash occurs, and the solution is make UIDocumentInteractionController object is "retain" for non ARC, i did that, but problem still there: in:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571212/crash-wen-tapping-open-in-instagram-while-using-uidocumentinteractioncontrolle, also i don't use ARC.

Comment: I got that from exception breakpoint: -[__NSCFSet _openDocumentWithApplication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb95d00, this after click on "Open in Instagram" button

Comment: If you are not using ARC you should be calling `retain` on your controller.  I don't see you doing that.  Why don't you just use ARC?

Comment: Also, `_docfile` is undefined when you assign `UTI`.  Then you make a new one in `setupControllerWithURL:usingDelegate:`.  Then you make another one.  Why?

Comment: @AaronBrager, thank you for reply, Actually i do that:@property (nonatomic, retain)     UIDocumentInteractionController* docController;, isn't that enough to make retain ?, Also we have an issue about camera frames per/second, so we don't use ARC, I use now the first example code of _docController.

Comment: "isn't that enough to make retain ?,"  No.  You are bypassing the property by accessing the instance variable directly (`_docController = …`).  The property will only `retain` it for you if you use it (`self.docController = …`).

Comment: Also, there is no issue related to frames per second that should be solved by switching from ARC to MRC.  If you are getting different behavior in MRC than ARC, then there is a bug in your MRC implementation.

Comment: @AaronBrager, Thank you very much, you saved my life, it works now, by (salf. not only using _doc), Also, I'm new in this project and they don't use ARC that they are working on augmented reality SDK which doesn't support ARC, I think may we can use ARC but I'm still learning. Thank you again.

Comment: @user306481 I'm glad it worked.  Remember that you can disable ARC on a per-class basis, so you can use ARC in most of your project.

Comment: @AaronBrager, it's a good info, i'll search about, Thank you, I'm sorry for disturbance but can I ask if you did share from iOS on Instagram before or Whatsapp?

Comment: I can replicate this crash. The stack trace is not very helpful as it's just tracing through the system dispatching the touch event.